# simple validation on form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to made simple validation form using jquery, ( **no 3rd party plugins**)
for this i wrote following code..

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
        <style>
        .InvaildField {
             border: 0.5px solid red;
        }
    </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#btnSubmit').attr("disabled", true);
                $('.emptyField').blur(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == '') {
                        $(this).removeAttr('class');
                        $(this).addClass('InvaildField');
                        $('#btnSubmit').attr("disabled", true);
                    } else {
                        $(this).removeAttr('class');
                        $('#btnSubmit').attr("disabled", false);
                    }
                });
                $('.emptyField').keyup(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == '') {
                        $(this).removeAttr('class');
                        $(this).addClass('InvaildField');
                        $('#btnSubmit').attr("disabled", true);
                    } else {
                        $(this).removeAttr('class');
                        $('#btnSubmit').attr("disabled", false);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td><input  class="emptyField" type="text"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td><input class="emptyField" type="text"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mobile Number</td>
                    <td><input class="emptyField" type="text"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input id="btnSubmit" class="emptyField" type="button" value="Submit"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

but **problem is when i fill first text box , button is enable**, how to enable button when all texboxes are not null ,

http://jsfiddle.net/xA7hH/

Comment: Instead of `removeAttr(class)`, you should use `removeClass` with the class you want to remove, this way, you will not remove classes for styling or other that you added afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Guess this would help you:

```
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input  class="emptyField" onkeyup="check()" type="text"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><input class="emptyField" onkeyup="check()" type="text"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mobile Number</td>
                <td><input class="emptyField" onkeyup="check()" type="text"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input id="btnSubmit" class="emptyField" disabled="disabled" type="button" value="Submit"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function check(){
            var allFilled = true;
            $(".emptyField").each(function(){
                if(!$(this).val()){
                    allFilled = false;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if(allFilled)
                $('#btnSubmit').removeAttr("disabled")
            else
                 $('#btnSubmit').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Yep, it is not problem , what i wrote is for this working good

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('input[value=""]').length == $('input').length) {
  $('#btnSubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

If you have as many non-empty inputs as number of inputs, enable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#btnSubmit').attr("disabled", true);

            $('.emptyField').on("keyup blur", function () {

                if($(this).val().length == 0)
                {
                    $(this).addClass('InvaildField');
                }
                else
                {
                   $(this).removeClass('InvaildField');
                }


                var len = true;

                $(':text').each(function () {

                   if ($(this).val().length == 0) 
                    {
                        len = false;                    
                    }
                });

                if (!len) {        
                    $('#btnSubmit').attr("disabled", true);
                } else {
                    $('#btnSubmit').attr("disabled", false);
                }
            });

        });
        </script>
```

and change     `.InvaildField`  to

```
.InvaildField {
     border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: in your previous code it also happening , isn't it :) . i will fix it

Comment: Hi, you gave nice solution, but using this code, i got problem to show redborder when texbox is empty, i want to use your code

Comment: ya i'm eding it , please give mre some timwe ok :)